How to disable Copilot in Neovim
Im struggeling with a problem concerning my neovim config.
Im really struggeling and i think i must oversee something because the task can not be more easier.
Right now im struggeling to deactivate the Copilot suggestion with ":Copilot disable". It will still give me suggestions.
I thank i maybe have to do, that im using copilot-chat as well as copilot for autocomplete.
copilot.lua
    return {
  "zbirenbaum/copilot.lua",
    cmd = "Cpt",    
    event = "InsertEnter",
  config = function()
    require('copilot').setup({
  panel = {
    enabled = true,
    auto_refresh = true,
    keymap = {
      jump_prev = "[[",
      jump_next = "]]",
      accept = "<CR>",
      refresh = "gr",
      open = "<M-CR>"
    },
    layout = {
      position = "bottom", -- | top | left | right
      ratio = 0.4
    },
  },
  suggestion = {
    enabled = true,
    auto_trigger = true,
    hide_during_completion = true,
    debounce = 75,
    keymap = {
      accept = "<M-Right>",
      accept_word = false,
      accept_line = false,
      next = "<M-]>",
      prev = "<M-[>",
      dismiss = "<M-Left>",
    },
  },
  filetypes = {
    yaml = false,
    markdown = false,
    help = false,
    gitcommit = false,
    gitrebase = false,
    hgcommit = false,
    svn = false,
    cvs = false,
    ["."] = false,
  },
  copilot_node_command = 'node', -- Node.js version must be > 18.x
  server_opts_overrides = {},
    })
    end,
}

copilot-chat.lua
return {
  {
    "CopilotC-Nvim/CopilotChat.nvim",
    branch = "canary",
    dependencies = {
      { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" },         -- for curl, log wrapper
      { "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim" }, -- Use telescope for help actions
    },
    opts = {
      debug = false, -- Enable debugging
      show_help = true, -- Show help actions
      window = {
        layout = "vertical",
        relative = "editor",
        width = 0.4,
        border = "single"   
      },
      auto_follow_cursor = false,    -- Don't follow the cursor after getting response
    },
    config = function(_, opts)
      local chat = require("CopilotChat")
      local select = require("CopilotChat.select")
      -- Use unnamed register for the selection
      opts.selection = select.unnamed

      -- Override the git prompts message
      --opts.prompts.Commit = {
      --  prompt = "Write commit message for the change with commitizen convention",
      --  selection = select.gitdiff,
      --}
      --opts.prompts.CommitStaged = {
      --  prompt = "Write commit message for the change with commitizen convention",
      --  selection = function(source)
      --    return select.gitdiff(source, true)
      --  end,
      --}

      chat.setup(opts)

      vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("CopilotChatVisual", function(args)
        chat.ask(args.args, { selection = select.visual })
      end, { nargs = "*", range = true })

      -- Inline chat with Copilot
      vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("CopilotChatInline", function(args)
        chat.ask(args.args, {
          selection = select.visual,
            window = {
                layout = "vertical",
                relative = "editor",
                width = 0.4,
                border = "single"   
            },
        })
      end, { nargs = "*", range = true })

      -- Restore CopilotChatBuffer
      vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("CopilotChatBuffer", function(args)
        chat.ask(args.args, { selection = select.buffer })
      end, { nargs = "*", range = true })
    end,
    event = "VeryLazy",
    keys = {
      -- Show prompts actions with telescope
      {
        "<leader>ccp",
        function()
          local actions = require("CopilotChat.actions")
          require("CopilotChat.integrations.telescope").pick(actions.prompt_actions())
        end,
        desc = "CopilotChat - Prompt actions",
      },
      -- Code related commands
      { "<leader>cce", "<cmd>CopilotChatExplain<cr>",       desc = "CopilotChat - Explain code" },
      { "<leader>cct", "<cmd>CopilotChatTests<cr>",         desc = "CopilotChat - Generate tests" },
      { "<leader>ccr", "<cmd>CopilotChatReview<cr>",        desc = "CopilotChat - Review code" },
      { "<leader>ccR", "<cmd>CopilotChatRefactor<cr>",      desc = "CopilotChat - Refactor code" },
      { "<leader>ccn", "<cmd>CopilotChatBetterNamings<cr>", desc = "CopilotChat - Better Naming" },
      -- Chat with Copilot in visual mode
      {
        "<leader>ccv",
        ":CopilotChatVisual<ENTER>",
        mode = "x",
        desc = "CopilotChat - Open in vertical split",
      },
      {
        "<leader>ccx",
        ":CopilotChatInline<cr>",
        mode = "x",
        desc = "CopilotChat - Inline chat",
      },
      -- Custom input for CopilotChat
      {
        "<leader>cci",
        function()
          local input = vim.fn.input("Ask Copilot: ")
          if input ~= "" then
            vim.cmd("CopilotChat " .. input)
          end
        end,
        desc = "CopilotChat - Ask input",
      },
      -- Generate commit message based on the git diff
      {
        "<leader>ccm",
        "<cmd>CopilotChatCommit<cr>",
        desc = "CopilotChat - Generate commit message for all changes",
      },
      {
        "<leader>ccM",
        "<cmd>CopilotChatCommitStaged<cr>",
        desc = "CopilotChat - Generate commit message for staged changes",
      },
      -- Quick chat with Copilot
      {
        "<leader>ccq",
        function()
          local input = vim.fn.input("Quick Chat: ")
          if input ~= "" then
            vim.cmd("CopilotChatBuffer " .. input)
          end
        end,
        desc = "CopilotChat - Quick chat",
      },
      -- Debug
      { "<leader>ccd", "<cmd>CopilotChatDebugInfo<cr>",     desc = "CopilotChat - Debug Info" },
      -- Fix the issue with diagnostic
      { "<leader>ccf", "<cmd>CopilotChatFixDiagnostic<cr>", desc = "CopilotChat - Fix Diagnostic" },
      -- Clear buffer and chat history
      { "<leader>ccl", "<cmd>CopilotChatReset<cr>",         desc = "CopilotChat - Clear buffer and chat history" },
      -- Toggle Copilot Chat Vsplit
      { "<leader>ccv", "<cmd>CopilotChatToggle<cr>",        desc = "CopilotChat - Toggle Vsplit" },
    },
  },
}

init.lua
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("vim-options")
require("keymaps")
require("lazy").setup({
  spec = {
    { import = "plugins" }, -- loads all plugins in plugins/
  },
  defaults = {
    lazy = false, -- plugins are not lazy loaded by default
  },
})

Thank you in advance!!
